# IOS Bundle Signing project option is blank in VS for mac 2022?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-mac

Installed vs for mac 2022 on a new machine but the bundle signing option is just black/empty? I've tried all the latest stable updates. I'd really like to avoid installing the old version of Xamarin. Stackoverflow wont let me post the full detailed installation description but hopefully these are the most interesting.

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.0.6 (build 4)

Runtime
.NET 6.0.5 (64-bit)
Architecture: Arm64

NuGet
Version: 6.0.0.262

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.302
    6.0.100
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Runtime (Arm64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.7
    6.0.0

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.1.5.90
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-0-vsmac
Build date: 2022-07-07 17:09:33 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504)
Build 13F100

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 8.10.0.5 (Visual Studio Community)
Branch: d17-2
Build date: 2022-05-18 07:32:06-0400

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.10.0.5 (Visual Studio Community)
Branch: d17-2
Build date: 2022-05-18 07:32:07-0400

Build Information
Release ID: 1700060004
Git revision: 056076d45137bf76b73f62f871524da8890deb05
Build date: 2022-07-07 17:06:59+00
Build branch: release-17.0
Build lane: release-17.0

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.4.0
Darwin 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0
    Tue Apr 26 21:08:37 PDT 2022
```

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found another thread online that resolved the issue by commenting out the CodesignKey and CodesignProvision manually in the project file (for all configurations).

Worked for me! The bundle signing option view is displayed again and you can finish your setup.

E.g.

```
 <!--<CodesignKey>iPhone Developer: Your value here </CodesignKey>-->
 <!--<CodesignProvision> Your value here </CodesignProvision>-->
```

Comment: Microsoft on their finest. If you report this issue on community, they will simply close telling "Not enough information".

Comment: I love how someone (eg u) found that out. <3

Comment: damn Microsoft.... ‍♂️

Answer (score 8):

Just to extend answer from Cliffhanger. This is because your signing certificate for the selected debug or release profile isnt on this Mac. For example, if you had certificate in 1 mac and you changed to another Mac which doesn't have the certificate. Simple workaround without amending project file configuration is to select another debug or release configuration which doesnt have any signing yet For example, `Debug|IphoneSimulator` and select Sigining will show the Ui, there you can change `release profile` signing.

Answer (score 2):

Another follow up to Cliffhanger's answer. I have been struggling with this issue for at least 3 hours. My certificates and provisioning profiles had all expired. I tried using automatic provisioning and that indicated it was all good but then I kept getting a message saying the app had been signed using a distribution certificate and the debugger couldn't connect. I deleted all the old certificates from Connect and from KeyChain, manually recreated certificates and provisioning profiles. I followed Cliffhanger's answer to at least see the bundle signing dialog but still got the same message when trying to debug on a physical device. I finally stumbled on [this comment on github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10874#issuecomment-1290990216) from October 2022 which resolved the problem:

```
Hi @ikeoriaku123. This issue has been fixed and will be in an upcoming release.
In the meantime, if you go into your .csproj file and manually remove any line (if any)
that has
    <EnableCodeSigning>false</EnableCodeSigning>
and add a line that says
    <EnableCodeSigning>true</EnableCodeSigning>
```

In 2023 this should not be a problem. Every time I have to touch provisioning profiles for iOS dev in Visual Studio it's a nightmare and I dread it.

Comment: Upvote for the last sentence...

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue today and realized that this was due to the fact that there were no valid signing certificates in the keychain. Once we added one of our certificates to the keychain, the Bundle Signing screen showed the proper options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not, or maybe I'm doing it wrong? I exported the old e.g distribution certificate from another machine including the private key and added it to keychain to this new machine but still no luck? Also the Visual Studio on the old machine (with working certificates) shows the bundle signing option as blank.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

I had to create a provisioning profile on the Apple Developer Program page.

https://developer.apple.com/

Download and install it on the MAC.

And it worked as expected.

Comment: Download and install what? Your profile? Doesnt make any sense please clarify.

Comment: The profile that I created from the link. As I mentioned, I had to create a developper profile and than, download and install it on the machine on which I develop.

Comment: Must mean "provisioning profile"

Comment: Yes, provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not related to the issue VS for Mac had back then but from time to time I am getting the same issue (Blank signing page in VS).
Specifically, I faced "CodesignKey" text changing, which is causing Adhoc or Appstore builds to fail.
The below line is the correct one

```
<CodesignKey>Apple Development: YOUR_TEAM Development (593ERYUI9LR7)</CodesignKey>
```

What I faced was the front part of the line being replaced by debug or some other configuration text, look below

```
<CodesignKey>iPhone Developer: YOUR_TEAM Development (593ERYUI9LR7)</CodesignKey>
```

This can be fixed by running VS from windows, but keep these details in mind if you end up a situation like this