# Unable to run iOS project in VS 2022 for Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I just upgraded from VS 2019 to VS 2022 for Mac. I'm now unable to "run" a project in iOS Simulator. I can build it just fine. I can "run" the project on Android Emulator just fine.

I'm only presented with the "Hammer" icon and not the "Run/Arrow" icon.

VS 2022 Mac Version: 17.3.8
macOS Version: 12.6

I have tried the following:

- Full uninstall using the Microsoft-provided uninstall scripts.
- Full reinstall from scratch.
- I have XCode 14 and I have opened it to make sure it installed the additional components.

[image]

My iOS Bundle Signing window is empty:

[image]

Comment: Does your solution contain multiple projects? Are you targeting the correct one (i.e. is it your start up project?)  I don't _think_ that should make the debug button disappear but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have the iOS project as the Startup Project. It's a Xamarin solution. So, it has 4 projects: Main, Android, iOS and Test.

Comment: My problem might be the Deployment Target setting. However, I cannot figure out where you find that in VS 2022.

Comment: This issue seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939015/cant-run-a-xamarin-app-in-iphone-simulator-from-visual-studio-for-mac). Please take a look.

Comment: Didn't help. I also realized my iOS Bundle Signing settings window is blank (See above)

Comment: Well, find another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018751/ios-bundle-signing-project-option-is-blank-in-vs-for-mac-2022) which seems similar to your question.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you have valid certificate in your keychain?

Comment: I have valid Apple Developer and Distribution certificates. XCode 14 does not have the option to create iOS Developer certificates. Just Apple or Mac.

Comment: No problem when I create a new VS 2022 project. I get the 
Play" button and the iOS Bundle Signing page is working properly.

Comment: I get a lot of MacOS error: -25294 for the VisualStudio process in the console log messages.

Comment: Error -25294 seems something wrong with keychain. See this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675290)

Comment: I just created an empty project and reimported all my files into it. This fixed it.

Comment: That's really great!!! You could post an answer if you want for this question, that might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to create a new empty project and import all my files from the broken project.